# Common Lisp - Lists in list

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to make a function, which should give me a list of cities:

```
((London United-Kingdom)
(Paris France)
(New-York USA)
(Sydney Australia))
```

My code doesn't work, something is wrong but I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
(defun make-city (name country)
  (list name country))

(defun cities
       (list (make-city 'London 'United-Kingdom)
             (make-city 'Paris 'France)
             (make-city 'New-York 'USA)
             (make-city 'Sydney 'Australia)))
```

Does anyone know where is a problem? It must be in (defun cities....), but where?

Comment: I'm a beginner, in scheme is working but in common lisp doesn't.

Comment: Looking at the syntax of defun should help: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defun.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`defvar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm) ("define variable") instead of [`defun`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defun.htm) ("define function") for `cities`.

[Common Lisp is a "lisp-2", scheme is a "lisp-1".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578574/what-is-the-difference-between-lisp-1-and-lisp-2)

Comment: I tried add empty brackets to: `(defun cities () (list ....))` But `defvar` is better, thanks.