# How does funcall work in Common Lisp?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

I don't understand what `funcall` would do in this example. I need an explanation about when the code will execute.

```
(defun total-value (field L)
  "Answer average value of fields of complex entries in list L"
  (if (null L)
    0
    (+ (funcall field (first L))
       (total-value field (rest L)))))
```

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

This function computes the sum of `field`s in `L`. It is equivalent to

```
(reduce #'+ L :key field)
```

or (much worse! don't ever do this!)

```
(apply #'+ (mapcar field L))
```

Here `field` is a function which extracts a numeric value from an element of `L`; [`funcall`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm) is the artifact of Common Lisp being [Lisp-2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4578574/850781): `(funcall field ...)` in Scheme (or any other Lisp-1) would look like `(field ...)`.

More specifically; [`funcall`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm) takes its first argument and [coerces](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_coerce.htm) it into a function; then it calls this function on all its other arguments.