# Why does the following elisp code not working?

Tags: elisp

I want to make each `mu4e-*-folder` a lambda function which takes `msg` as a function, while `folder` is set to produce this lambda function.

```
(defun my-get-eval-func (folder)
  (lambda (msg)
    (my-mu4e-get-folder folder msg)))

(dolist (folder (list
                  'mu4e-sent-folder
                  'mu4e-drafts-folder
                  'mu4e-trash-folder
                  'mu4e-refile-folder))
  (set folder (my-get-eval-func folder)))
```

The code above seems not working. Why and what's the correct way to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Lisp-1 and Lisp-2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578574/what-is-the-difference-between-lisp-1-and-lisp-2)

Comment: @sds Probably "dynamic-by-default is different from lexical-by-default".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Emacs Lisp is dynamically scoped, so closures don't work:

```
(defun adder (x) #'(lambda (y) (+ x y)))
(funcall (adder 3) 4)
```

yields the error "void variable x", as the call to the lambda expression is trying to access `x` in the current dynamic environment.  You can either tell Emacs to use lexical binding (Section 11.9.3 of the Emacs Lisp manual), or inline the value of `x` manually:

```
(defun adder (x) `(lambda (y) (+ ',x y)))
```

In your case, this means doing something like:

```
(defun my-get-eval-func (folder)
  `(lambda (msg)
     (my-mu4e-get-folder ',folder msg)))
```

Note further that Emacs Lisp is a Lisp-2, meaning that each symbol has two bindings ­— the value binding and the function binding.  You didn't specify which binding you want to set, but if it is the function binding, you will need to replace `set` with `fset` in your code (see Section 12.8 of the Emacs Lisp manual).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`fset`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Cells.html) instead of of `set`.

Comment: I think the issue is about expecting closures in a dynamically scoped Lisp, not about the function cell.