# How to set a function in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In Common Lisp, I can get a function to pass around with the `#'` syntax, like this:

```
(let ((x #'+))
 (funcall x 1 2))
```

But suppose I want to set a function so I don't have to use `funcall` for it. Does Common Lisp have a local function name table, or just the global one that is assigned to with `defun`?

Is there a way to assign to a function symbol other than `defun`? Or more generally: is there a way I can do something similar to this nonworking example:

```
(setf #'x #'+)
(x 1 2)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define a local function using
[`flet` and `labels`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_flet_.htm):

```
(flet ((f (x) (1+ (* 2 x))))
  (f 7))
==> 15
```

You can also set function definition of a symbol using [`fdefinition`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fdefin.htm):

```
(setf (fdefinition 'f) #'+)
(f 1 2 3)
==> 6
```

Note that [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm) binds the
[value cell](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_v.htm#value_cell) of the symbol while `flet` bind the [function cell](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_cell).
When the symbol appears in the "function" position, the "function"
cell is used, while when it appears in the "value" position, the "value"
cell is used:

```
(setf (symbol-function 'x) #'car)
(setf (symbol-value 'x) #'cdr)
(x '(1 . 2))
==> 1
(funcall x '(1 . 2))
==> 2
```

Similarly,

```
(flet ((x (o) (car o)))
  (let ((x #'cdr))
    (cons (x '(1 . 2))
          (funcall x '(1 . 2)))))
==> (1 . 2)
```

This is the [difference between Lisp-1 and Lisp-2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4578574/850781).

Finally, note that [CLISP](http://clisp.org) is just one implementation of the language [ANSI Common Lisp](http://clhs.lisp.se/Front/).

Comment: Is there something which is like a combination of `let` and `(setf (fdefinition ...))`? E.g. `(let ((x #'+)) (x 3 4)) ==> 7`, as in the original question?

Comment: No, because Common Lisp is a [lisp-2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4578574/850781). You would need scheme for that.

Comment: But you could get this behavior by writing a macro that expands to `(flet ((x (&rest args) (apply f args))) (x 3 4))` given an input like `(this-macro ((x f)) (x 3 4))`, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

One option for getting this kind of behavior is to write a macro to do it.

```
(defmacro flet* (assignments &body body)
  (let ((assignments (mapcar
                      (lambda (assn)
                        (list (first assn) '(&rest args)
                              (list 'apply (second assn) 'args)))
                      assignments)))
    `(flet ,assignments ,@body)))
```

This macro translates `flet*` into `flet` + `apply` like this:

```
(flet* ((x #'+)
        (y #'*))
       (pprint (x 1 2))
       (pprint (y 3 4))
       (pprint (x (y 2 3) 4)))
```

Becomes:

```
(flet ((x (&rest args) (apply #'+ args))
       (y (&rest args) (apply #'* args)))
       (pprint (x 1 2))
       (pprint (y 3 4))
       (pprint (x (y 2 3) 4)))
```