# How to use `apply-partially`?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to use apply-partially in a local context:

```
((apply-partially '+ 1) `(1))
```

This give me the following error: `eval: Invalid function: (apply-partially (quote +) 1)`

similarly:

```
(let ((addone (apply-partially #'+ 1)))
  (addone 2))
```

Why any of this example doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because Emacs Lisp has separate namespaces for variables and functions.  A function that has been defined using `defun` can be called by putting its name first in a list and evaluating that, but if you have a function as a value (as returned by `apply-partially`) you need to use `funcall` or `apply`.

The difference between `funcall` and `apply` is that `funcall` just calls the function with the arguments given, while `apply` treats its last argument as a list that should be appended to the argument list.  Thus, your first example needs to be written with `apply`, since `+` doesn't work with lists:

```
(apply (apply-partially '+ 1) `(1))
```

For your second example, use `funcall`, since the function argument is not wrapped in a list:

```
(let ((addone (apply-partially #'+ 1)))
  (funcall addone 2))
```

---

This is sometimes referred to as "Lisp-1" vs "Lisp-2". "Lisp-1" languages such as Scheme and Clojure have one namespace for variables and functions, while "Lisp-2" languages such as Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp have separate namespaces. See also:

- [What is the difference between Lisp-1 and Lisp-2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578574/what-is-the-difference-between-lisp-1-and-lisp-2)
- http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/lisp1_vs_lisp2.html
- https://andersmurphy.com/2019/03/08/lisp-1-vs-lisp-2.html

The way it works in Emacs Lisp is that each symbol has multiple "cells", one for its value as a variable and one for its function definition.  So the function cell of the symbol `list` contains the built-in function, while you're free to put whatever value you want in its `value` cell. (This doesn't apply to lexical variables, which are stored in a "lexical environment" instead of in value cells of symbols.)

In fact, each symbol has a third cell holding its property list. You can access individual properties of a symbol using the `get` and `put` functions, and you can get the entire properly list by calling `symbol-plist`. So you could say that Emacs Lisp has more than 2 namespaces, despite it being called a "Lisp-2" language.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you.