# + Vector Common Lisp

Tags: vector, common-lisp

I can seem to figure out why the following command outputs the following

```
(vector + 1 2)
(vector + 1 2)
=> #((VECTOR + 1 2) 1 2)
```

Where am I setting `+`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not setting it, the [REPL](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/25_aa.htm) sets the following variable after evaluating each form you give it:

- [`+`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pl_plp.htm) - the last *form*
- [`-`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v__.htm) - the current *form*
- [`/`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_sl_sls.htm) - the last form's *values* as a list
- [`*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v__stst_.htm) - the last form's *primary value* (`(car /)`)

This is somewhat similar to the [history facility of most modern Unix shells](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html).

PS. An important aspect of your problem is that [Common Lisp is Lisp-2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4578574/850781), so [the symbol `+` names **both** a variable and a function](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/a_pl.htm).

Comment: Please elaborate.  Why is set and when? Or is it a bug?

Comment: No not particularly.  Why?  I can't think of something similar happening in unix.

Comment: Wait...so it's like a history if so do you mind adding an exert for each.

Comment: If you don't mind adding an exert for each so it is a self contained answer I will gladly accept otherwise as it stands it is not really a self contained answer but merely links to lisp.se

Comment: SO cannot be a replacement for RTFM.