# common lisp: apply needs special treatment?

Tags: common-lisp

If I try this

```
(apply (first '(numberp)) '(17))
```

all is well, returning `T`. But this

```
(apply numberp '(17))
```

gets `The variable NUMBERP is unbound.`

But this

```
(apply #'numberp '(17))
```

works. I'm obviously missing something very basic here. . . .

Comment: Even supposing that a variable is bound, note that **(let ((x 10)) (first '(x)))** returns the symbol **x**, but **(let ((x 10)) x)** returns 10. So, your code tries to apply two different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing here is how the Common Lisp [reading](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_b.htm) and [evaluation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_a.htm) works.

When you give CL text, e.g.,

```
(apply (first '(numberp)) '(17))
```

the reader (you can [invoke](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) it yourself!) parses it into the following list:

```
(apply (first (quote (numberp))) (quote (17)))
```

(note that `'` is just syntactic sugar for [`quote`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm)) which is then evaluated like this:

1. take the function binding of the first element of the list, `apply`
2. evaluate the second list element:

   1. take the function binding of  `first`
   2. evaluate the second list element:

      - since it is quoted, take it as is, get list of length 1 with element `numberp`
   3. apply `first` to that list, get `numberp`
3. evaluate the 3rd list element:

   - since it is quoted, it is just the thing under `quote`, i.e., list of length 1 with element `17`
4. apply the first function (`apply`) to the arguments, i.e., apply the (function binding of) `numberp` to the list of one element - 17.

Your 2nd form differs from the 1st in that you have symbol `numberp` which is evaluated as a variable and thus you get your error.

In your 3rd form you use `#'numberp` which the reader transforms to `(function numberp)` which returns a *function* value which can be applied to the list.

In short, this is the result of Common Lisp being [Lisp-2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4578574/850781).

You might also find [When to use 'quote in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134887/850781) instructive.

Answer (score 1):

What `(apply numberp '(17))` does is lookup the value of the *variable* numberp. This has nothing to do with `apply`. Unquoted symbols in the function position, the first element in the list, are looked-up in the function namespace, the successive elements are looked-up in the variable namespace.

If you try `(+ x 1)` you would get the same error. Or `(symbol-function symbol-function)` for that matter.

For `(apply numberp '(17))` to work you would need to bind the variable numberp to a function. For example:

```
(let ((numberp 'numberp))
  (apply numberp '(17)))
```