# Difference between flet vs let+funcall

Tags: common-lisp, let

These are two related questions actually.

1. What is the difference between flet and let for binding functions.
2. Are the examples A and B below equivalent?

A)

```
(flet ((myfun (x) (+ x 3)))
  (myfun 3))
```

B)

```
(let ((myfun (lambda (x) (+ x 3))))
  (funcall myfun 3))
```

NB:

```
(let ((myfun (lambda (x) (+ x 3))))
  (myfun 3))
```

will throw an error "myfun" undefined operator.

Comment: The first example should be `(flet ((myfun (x) (+ x 3))) (myfun 3))`.

Comment: -is this not what I wrote under A)?

Comment: No, your first version was identical to the code after NB. You can check that in the revision history.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start from your second question:

> 2. Are the examples A and B below equivalent?

As the answer of @sds discusses in detail, both are semantically equivalent, even if A is compiled more efficiently by most Common Lisp compilers (and this can be easily understood because B requires an additional call to the high level function `funcall`).

Now, for your first question:

> 1. What is the difference between flet and let for binding functions.

One difference is that, since Common Lisp is a Lisp-2 language (see for instance this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578574/what-is-the-difference-between-lisp-1-and-lisp-2)), the example A binds the name of function `myfun` to a functional object, while the second one bind a normal lexical variable to the same functional object.

The consequence is that, from a practical point of view, a part from efficiency, there are differences both in syntax (a more convenient way for calling the functional object, like your example shows), and in semantics (for instance, the function defines a named-block, so that one can write something like: `(flet ((myfun (x) (when (< x 0) (return-from myfun 0)) (+ x 3))) (myfun -4))`, not possible with a `let`).

But maybe the most important point is that `flet` is only a part of the twin special operators `flet`, `labels` to define local functions (together with `macrolet` to define local macros, see the [specification](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm)). And with the `labels` operator you can define *recursive* local functions, which is not possible with let.

Comment: You would have to explicitly make a `block` in an anonymous lambda to enable an early `return-from`, so it is not impossible but inconvenient.

Answer (score 3):

[`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm) creates new variable bindings.

[`flet`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_flet_.htm) define local functions.

They serve different purposes.

Your examples do the same thing, but they might be compiled differently (example A is more "orthodox" and thus is more likely to be more efficient).  E.g., in [CLISP](http://clisp.org):

```
[1]> (disassemble '(flet ((myfun (x) (+ x 3))) (myfun 3)))

Disassembly of function :LAMBDA
(CONST 0) = 3
(CONST 1) = #<COMPILED-FUNCTION :LAMBDA-MYFUN>
0 required arguments
0 optional arguments
No rest parameter
No keyword parameters
4 byte-code instructions:
0     (CONST&PUSH 0)                      ; 3
1     (CONST 1)                           ; #<COMPILED-FUNCTION :LAMBDA-MYFUN>
2     (CALLC)
3     (SKIP&RET 1)
NIL
[2]> (disassemble '(let ((myfun (lambda (x) (+ x 3)))) (funcall myfun 3)))

Disassembly of function :LAMBDA
(CONST 0) = #<COMPILED-FUNCTION :LAMBDA-1>
(CONST 1) = 3
0 required arguments
0 optional arguments
No rest parameter
No keyword parameters
5 byte-code instructions:
0     (CONST&PUSH 0)                      ; #<COMPILED-FUNCTION :LAMBDA-1>
1     (LOAD&PUSH 0)
2     (CONST&PUSH 1)                      ; 3
3     (FUNCALL 1)
5     (SKIP&RET 2)
NIL
```

or [SBCL](http://sbcl.org):

```
*  (disassemble (lambda () (flet ((myfun (x) (+ x 3))) (myfun 3))))

; disassembly for (LAMBDA ())
; Size: 22 bytes. Origin: #x1003BD6D94
; 94:       498B4C2460       MOV RCX, [R12+96]                ; thread.binding-stack-pointer
                                                              ; no-arg-parsing entry point
; 99:       48894DF8         MOV [RBP-8], RCX
; 9D:       BA0C000000       MOV EDX, 12
; A2:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; A5:       F8               CLC
; A6:       5D               POP RBP
; A7:       C3               RET
; A8:       CC10             BREAK 16                         ; Invalid argument count trap
NIL
*  (disassemble (lambda () (let ((myfun (lambda (x) (+ x 3)))) (funcall myfun 3))))

; disassembly for (LAMBDA ())
; Size: 34 bytes. Origin: #x1003C40804
; 04:       498B4C2460       MOV RCX, [R12+96]                ; thread.binding-stack-pointer
                                                              ; no-arg-parsing entry point
; 09:       48894DF8         MOV [RBP-8], RCX
; 0D:       BA06000000       MOV EDX, 6
; 12:       488B0597FFFFFF   MOV RAX, [RIP-105]               ; #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA
                                                              ;                #) ..>
; 19:       B902000000       MOV ECX, 2
; 1E:       FF7508           PUSH QWORD PTR [RBP+8]
; 21:       FF60FD           JMP QWORD PTR [RAX-3]
; 24:       CC10             BREAK 16                         ; Invalid argument count trap
NIL
```

As you can see, the `flet` version is more efficient.