# Illegal function call when sharp-quoting a lambda

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp

If these two expressions are equivalent

```
CL-USER> (lambda (x) (+ x 10))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X)) {530321CB}>

CL-USER> #'(lambda (x) (+ x 10))
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (X)) {5303226B}>
```

then why do I get the illegal function call error here

```
CL-USER> (#'(lambda (x) (+ x 10)) 10)
```

while this

```
CL-USER> ((lambda (x) (+ x 10)) 10)
20 (5 bits, #x14, #o24, #b10100)
```

works perfectly well?

PS I am using SBCL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Different valid LAMBDAs**

```
(lambda (x) (+ x 10))
```

`LAMBDA` is a macro which expands to `(function (lambda ...))`.

```
#'(lambda (x) (+ x 10))
```

`#'` is a reader macro which expands at read time into `(function ...)`.

`((lambda ...) ...)` is built-in syntax in Common Lisp. It's defined as a valid form, a valid Lisp expression.

**Invalid Lisp form syntax using a LAMBDA**

`((function (lambda ...)) ...)` is not valid syntax in Lisp.

**Valid syntax of compound Lisp forms**

There are only the following compound forms valid in Common Lisp:

- `(<special-operator> ...)` for one of the built-in special operators
- `(<macro-operator> ...)`
- `(<function-operator> ...)`
- `(<lambda-expression> ...)`

The operators are symbols. The latter then has a lambda expression as its first element. Example:

`((lambda (x) (1+ x)) 41)`

Other syntactic variants are not valid in Common Lisp. Thus `((function (lambda ...)) ...)` and also `(#'(lambda ...) ...)`is not valid syntax.

**Note**

above is slightly confusing, but that's how it is defined in the language standard. The `lambda` macro was added later after the initial design of Common Lisp. It allows us to write similar to Scheme:

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) (+ x 2)) '(1 2 3))
```

But it is still not the case that the first element of a list gets evaluated, like in Scheme.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is just a syntactic rule: a form to be interpreted as a function call can be either (see the Common Lisp [Glossary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_a.htm)):

a) **function form**, a form that is a list and that has a first element which is the name of a function to be called on arguments which are the result of evaluating subsequent elements of the function form.

b) **a lambda form**, a form that is a list and that has a first element which is a lambda expression representing a function to be called on arguments which are the result of evaluating subsequent elements of the lambda form.

In other words, a list which is form which must be interpreted as a function call can have as first element only either a symbol, the function name, or a list starting with `lambda`, i.e. a lambda expression. No other expressions are allowed (and `#'x` is just an abbreviation for `(function x)`, which is not one of the two cases).

This is due to the well known fact that Common Lisp follows the Lisp-2 model (see [What is the difference between Lisp-1 and Lisp-2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578574/what-is-the-difference-between-lisp-1-and-lisp-2)).