# Lisp - Functions passed into another function as arguments and called from within a Let

Tags: lisp, slime

I am learning Lisp and, just for practice/education, am trying to define a function that will

1. ask the user to enter a number until they enter an integer > 0 [copied from Paul Graham's Ansi Common Lisp]
2. print that number and subtract 1 from it, repeat until the number hits 0, then return.

I am trying to do this via passing 2 functions into a higher-order function - one to get the number from the user, and another recursive [just for fun] function that prints the number while counting it down to 0.

Right now my higher-order function is not working correctly [I've tested the first 2 and they work fine] and I cannot figure out why. I am using SBCL in SLIME. My code for the 3 functions looks like this:

```
(defun ask-number ()
  (format t "Please enter a number. ")
  (let ((val (read))) ; so val is a single-item list containing the symbol 'read'?
    (cond             ; no here read is a function call
      ((numberp val)
       (cond
     ((< val 0) (ask-number))
     (T val)))
      (t (ask-number))))))

(defun count-down (n)
  (cond
    ((eql n 0) n)
    (t
     (progn
       (format t "Number is: ~A ~%" n)
       (let ((n (- n 1)))
       (count-down n))))))

(defun landslide (f1 f2)
  (let (x (f1))
    (progn
      (format t "x is: ~A ~%" x)
      (f2 x)))))
```

but calling  `slime-eval-defun` in `landslide` yields:

```
; SLIME 2.27; in: DEFUN LANDSLIDE
;     (F1)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable F1 is defined but never used.

;     (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA LANDSLIDE
;         (F1 F2)
;       (BLOCK LANDSLIDE
;         (LET (X (F1))
;           (PROGN (FORMAT T "x is: ~A ~%" X) (F2 X)))))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable F1 is defined but never used.
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable F2 is defined but never used.
; in: DEFUN LANDSLIDE
;     (F2 X)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: COMMON-LISP-USER::F2
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     F2
;   caught 4 STYLE-WARNING conditions
```

I have tried several [what I consider] obvious modifications to the code, and they all fail with different warnings. Calling the function like `(landslide (ask-number) (count-down))`, `ask-number` prompts for user input as expected, but then SLIME fails with

```
invalid number of arguments: 0
   [Condition of type SB-INT:SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR]
```

I know I have to be missing something really obvious; can someone tell me what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: You are missing a set of parens in your [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm):

You have `(let (x (f1)) ...)` which binds 2 variables `x` and `f1` to `nil`.

What you want is `(let ((x (f1))) ...)` which binds 1 variable `x` to the values of function call `(f1)`

**Second**: Common Lisp is a ["lisp-2"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4578574/850781), so to call `f2` you need to use [`funcall`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm): `(funcall f2 ...)`.

**Finally**: all your `progn`s are unnecessary, and your code is hard to read because of broken indentation, you can use Emacs to fix it.

Comment: Thanks - I made all the edits, but I still get the above error when calling (landslide (ask-number) (count-down)) - the one that says I'm passing count-down 0 arguments.

Comment: @zeroclaim: you are passing to `landslide`  the _result_ of a call to `(count-down)` which indeed has no arguments. what you want is `(landslide #'ask-number #'count-down)`

Answer (score 1):

Before I reach an error in `landslide`, there are some notes about this code:

Your first function is hard to read- not just because of indentation, but because of nested [`cond`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm).

- You should always think about how to simplify condition branches- using [`and`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_and.htm), [`or`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_or.htm), and if you have only two branches of code, use [`if`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_if.htm) instead.
- There are predicates [`plusp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_minusp.htm#plusp) and [`minusp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_minusp.htm#minusp).
- Also, don't forget to [flush](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_finish.htm).

I'd rewrite this as:

```
(defun ask-number ()
  (format t "Please enter a number. ")
  (finish-output)
  (let ((val (read)))
    (if (and (numberp val)
             (plusp val))
        val
      (ask-number))))
```

Second function, `count-down`.

- `(eql n 0)` is [`zerop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_zerop.htm#zerop)
- `cond` here has only two branches, `if` can be better
- `cond` has implicit `progn`, so don't use `progn` inside `cond`
- `let` is unnecessary here, you can use [`1-`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_1pl_1_.htm) directly when you call `count-down`

Suggested edit:

```
(defun count-down (n)
  (if (zerop n) n
    (progn 
      (format t "Number is: ~A ~%" n)
      (count-down (1- n)))))
```

Also, this function can be rewritten using [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_loop.htm#loop) and `downto` keyword, something like:

```
(defun count-down (n)
  (loop for i from n downto 0
        do (format t "Number is: ~A ~%" i)))
```

And finally, `landslide`. You have badly formed `let` here and as Common Lisp is Lisp-2, you have to use [`funcall`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_funcal.htm#funcall). Note that `let` has also implicit `progn`, so you can remove your `progn`:

```
(defun landslide (f1 f2)
  (let ((x (funcall f1)))
    (format t "x is: ~A ~%" x)
    (finish-output)
    (funcall f2 x)))
```

Then you call it like this:
`(landslide #'ask-number #'count-down)`