# How can I call a LISP function with &optional arg and colon like `(formato '((:year 0 4) (:month 4 6) (:day 6 8)))`

Tags: datetime, lisp, common-lisp, pgloader

I am trying to perform a DB migration with [pgloader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/) and I would like to define a [custom lisp transformation file for a datetime](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/transforms.html), but I don't know LISP (!)

So I have cut&paste one of the [pgloader transform functions](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/blob/master/src/utils/transforms.lisp#L127) and I tried to invoke it with no luck after spending a bunch of hours (!) in studying LISP.

I have extracted and simplified the function

```
(defun date-with-no-separator
    (date-string
     &optional (formato '((:year     0  4)
                          (:month    4  6)
                          (:day      6  8)
                          (:hour     8 10)
                          (:minute  10 12)
                          (:seconds 12 14))))
  "Apply this function when input date in like '20041002152952'"

  (let ((str-length      (length date-string))
        (expected-length (reduce #'max (mapcar #'third formato))))
    (print str-length)
    (print expected-length)))
```

I have changed `format` to `formato` in order to be sure that it is a variable and not the `format` LISP function. It seems to me that I have been right at least in this assumption. Am I?

I have tried:

```
(setq my-date "20041002152952")
(date-with-no-separator my-date)
```

and by running `clisp test.lisp` I got the output

```
14
14
```

and then I have done some failing attempts that you can see below with ANY LUCK:

```
(setq my-date "2004")
; (setf (get 'formato 'year) '(0 4))
(setq formato (#':year 0 4))

(date-with-no-separator my-date formato) ;(formato (:year 0 4))) ; '((12 16) (6 8) (1 3)) ))
```

At this time I just expect to get

```
4
4
```

when I set my-date to "2004" and my format to (:year 0 4)
but also

```
10
10
```

when I set my-date to "01/01/1970" and my format to (:year 6 10) (:month 3 5) (:day 0 2)

I am a pythonist if it could be useful to make me understanding the topic with pythonic examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, `format` is a variable here, but Common Lisp is [Lisp2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578574/what-is-the-difference-between-lisp-1-and-lisp-2), so variables can have the same name as functions and you don't overwrite core function.

Optional argument `formato` is a list, containing triplets `(keyword number number)`- so if you want to provide your own format, it has to have exactly this form.

And you probably don't need `setq` here- you can write the values of arguments into a function call or use [`let`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/s_let_l.htm).

Here are some examples:

```
> (date-with-no-separator "2004" '((:year 0 4)))

4 
4 
4

> (date-with-no-separator "01/01/1970" '((:year 6 10) (:month 3 5) (:day 0 2)))

10 
10 
10

> (let ((date "01/01/1970")
        (format '((:year 6 10) (:month 3 5) (:day 0 2))))
   (date-with-no-separator date format))

10 
10 
10
```

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. I don't really know why I didn't succeed in this, maybe I messed up with ( and ' as a lisp newbie. Thank you a lot, I can proceed my challenge with pgloader ;-)

Comment: @fero if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: thank you @martin-půda. My first question on SO, now I have accepted your useful answer

Answer (score 3):

> (setq formato (#':year 0 4))

Above makes no sense.

`#':year` is nothing useful:

- `#'foo` denotes a function `foo`
- `:year` denotes a keyword symbol.

`( .... )` denotes a form to be evaluated, for example a function call.

`(#':year 0 4)` thus tries to call the function object `:year`, which does not exist and if it would exist, then it can't be called like this.

Remember: when you want to pass lists as data you have to quote them:

`(:year 0 4)`  this is a list of three items: a keyword symbol and two integer numbers.

If you want to pass that as data you have to quote it:

`(list '(:year 0 4))` -> `((:year 0 4))`

If you want to have a list of lists you have either compute it or quote a list of lists:

computed:

`(list '(:year 0 4))` -> `((:year 0 4))`

or

`(list (list :year 0 4))` -> `((:year 0 4))`

quote it:

`'((:year 0 4))` -> `((:year 0 4))`

**summary**

this `(setq formato (#':year 0 4))` should be:

`(setq formato '((:year 0 4)))`

Comment: thx @rainer-joswig this is an useful answer for me. I find it less appropriate than the one provided by Martin, but since it is in topic imho, I have upvoted it.